# How do you override a nullable annotated generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I am trying to add nullability support to parts of an existing code base.  One area that has me stumped is how to override a generic method when the return value is nullable annotated.

```
#nullable enable
public class Stuff<T> {}

public abstract class Base {
    public virtual Stuff<T?>? MakeStuff<T>() => null;
    
    public Stuff<T?>? MakeStuff2<T>() => null;  
}


public abstract class Derived : Base {
    public override  Stuff<T?>? MakeStuff<T>() => base.MakeStuff<T>();
}
```

This results in a pair of error messages that don't quite make sense to me:

> Compilation error (line 26, col 29): 'Derived.MakeStuff()': return type must be 'Stuff<T?>' to match overridden member 'Base.MakeStuff()'

> Compilation error (line 26, col 29): The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

This all works when nullable is not enabled.

Comment: JetBrains Rider suggests this code `public override Stuff<T?>? MakeStuff<T>() where T : default => base.MakeStuff<T>();`. Note the `where T : default` constraint. I can't tell you what it means, but it seems to compile successfully (tried with C# 10 on .NET 6)

Comment: Ah, there's some useful information on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations#default-constraint

Comment: That seems to do the trick, although it is really strange that you only need to apply the constraint on the derived class.  Actually that really strikes me as odd that I am even allowed to apply an additional constraint on an override.

Comment: @JeremyRichards it is special constraint created just because you can't apply constraints on overridden and explicitly implemented generic methods =)

Comment: Reading the docs that Emanuel suggested, it seems like "where T:default" isn't a real constraint, it is just some special syntax to resolve a parse issue with the C# compiler where it cannot tell if T? refers to a nullable reference type or Nullable<T> (where T is a value type).  I am confused why the parse issue only occurs with overrides rather than on the base function, but I am content that it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [@Emanuel’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979191/how-do-you-override-a-nullable-annotated-generic-method-in-c/69996490#comment123703188_69979191), which pointed me in the right direction.

The answer is to use the `where T:default` constraint, which solves the issue in C# 9 and above.

Comment: Can you flesh out this answer with the resulting code? Basically, give the kind of quality answer you would hope to find if you came here with the same question.